# Is it possible for fuselages to have a negative lift coefficient at positive angle of attacks?

Tags: falcon-9, entry-descent-landing, lift

Recently I was interested in the descent phase of the first stage of the falcon 9 launch vehicle. I assumed a long cylinder to represent the first stage. using DATCOM to predict aerodynamics coefficients, it gives negative lift coefficients at positive angle of attacks up to 5 degrees at different Mach numbers. Is it possible or it's an error?

Comment: Comment instead of answer because I'm not an aerodynamicist, but I don't find that surprising for a flat-ended cylinder model. At small positive AoA, the front face presents a large cross section producing downforce (negative lift), while the underside of the cylinder is a smaller cross section producing upforce. A cylinder with a finely tapered front end would produce positive lift.